# How to change the settings for bluetooth from Android terminal emulator?

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, terminal-emulator

In my phone I try to send an file to another mobile using Bluetooth transfer. when I am enabling Bluetooth then now show this error message: WLAN close first. further I try to enable the WiFi alternatively error displayed Bluetooth first close. How to rectify this error in terminal emulator support. But I have a super user permission for this mobile.